Getting 2 errors while installing skater package in python Google Colab, the errors are conflicting dependencies and Resolution impossible error
!pip install skater

Collecting skater

  Downloading skater-1.1.2.tar.gz (96 kB)

     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 96.7/96.7 kB 1.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00

  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.18 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from skater) (1.2.2)

Collecting scikit-image==0.14 (from skater)

  Downloading scikit-image-0.14.0.tar.gz (27.0 MB)

     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 27.0/27.0 MB 17.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00

  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.22.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from skater) (2.0.3)

INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of skater to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.

Collecting skater

  Downloading skater-1.1.0.tar.gz (52 kB)

     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 52.5/52.5 kB 1.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00

  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

  Downloading skater-1.0.4.tar.gz (41 kB)

     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 41.4/41.4 kB 687.0 kB/s eta 0:00:00

  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

  Downloading skater-1.0.2.tar.gz (37 kB)

  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

  Downloading skater-1.0.1.tar.gz (36 kB)

  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

ERROR: Cannot install skater==1.0.1, skater==1.0.2, skater==1.0.4, skater==1.1.0 and skater==1.1.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.



The conflict is caused by:

    skater 1.1.2 depends on ds-lime>=0.1.1.21

    skater 1.1.0 depends on ds-lime>=0.1.1.21

    skater 1.0.4 depends on ds-lime>=0.1.1.21

    skater 1.0.2 depends on ds-lime>=0.1.1.21

    skater 1.0.1 depends on ds-lime>=0.1.1.21



To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified

2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict



ERROR: ResolutionImpossible:for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts

I tried to install skater package in python Google Colab, but I am getting the above two errors. I have visited the link mentioned but not able to understand how to solve this issue.

did you try install ds-lime>=0.1.1.21 before skater?

Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

I found tutorial on Kaggle which installs skater (and ds-lime) using conda. I found ds-lime in conda and it seems last version was created 5 years ago. It seems original module was created by DataScience.com but its page doesn't exist, and its GitHub also doesn't exist. Maybe this page was acquired by other pages (or company) and they removes all data. It seems you may have to use conda to work with it.

conda has ds-lime as [files tar.bz2] and you may download it, extract itm and you may try to put manually files from site-packages in some folder with python modules

skater needs module ds-lime but it seems ds-lime doesn't exists any more.
I found tutorial on Kaggle which installs skater (and ds-lime) using conda. I found ds-lime in conda and it seems last version was created 5 years ago. It seems original module was created by DataScience.com but its page doesn't exist, and its GitHub also doesn't exist. It seems it was acquired by oracle.com and probably they removed all data. It seems you may have to use conda to work with it.

Other idea: conda has ds-lime as files .tar.bz2 and you may download it, extract itm and you may try to put manually files from site-packages in folder with python modules.
I downloaded noarch/ds-lime-0.1.1.27-py_1.tar.bz2, extracted it, and I moved subfolders ds_lime-0.1.1.27-py2.7.egg-info and lime to /usr/lib/python3.10 and later install skater starts working. But now it has problem with other modules - scikit-image and wordcloud - so I can't check if skater can really work.
!wget https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ds-lime/0.1.1.27/download/noarch/ds-lime-0.1.1.27-py_1.tar.bz2

!tar -xvjf 'ds-lime-0.1.1.27-py_1.tar.bz2'

!cp -r site-packages/ds_lime-0.1.1.27-py2.7.egg-info /usr/lib/python3.10/
!cp -r site-packages/lime /usr/lib/python3.10/

Maybe problem is because it is very old code, and files for ds-lime have py36 in name which may suggest that it was created for Python 3.6. So it may need to install Python 3.6 to use it.
